# amazon linux - install openjdk-debuginfo?

Tags: java, linux, debugging, amazon-ec2

I was trying to use `jstack` on ec2 instance with `amazon linux`. so I installed `openjdk-devel` package.

```
sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64
```

But jstack raised exception `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

```
sudo -u tomcat jstack -J-d64 -m 941
```

After 15 min google session, I found some qna that said installing `openjdk-debuginfo` package might be helpful.

But how can I install `openjdk-debuginfo`? It is not on `yum search`.

Answer (score 5):

worked for me.

`sudo yum --enablerepo='*-debug*' install java-1.6.0-openjdk-debuginfo.x86_64`

from: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=557240